# How to access LWC DOM?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

Due to Shadow DOM and Locker Service, I am unable to access LWC DOM.
Is there any workaround for a 3rd Party JavaScript to access LWC DOM?

Comment: I always use ```this.template.querySelector()``` to access DOM in lwc.

Answer (score 1):

A third-party library can access a DOM element with `lwc:dom="manual"`:

```
<div lwc:dom="manual">
```

...

```
someLibrary(this.template.querySelector('div'));
```

Read more in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library).

Comment: I tried with lwc:dom="manual". It allows us to add child elements. But, it is not allowing us to read the data.

Comment: @MagulanDuraipandian What library is being used? What are you trying to do specifically? Without seeing any code, all we can give you is general advice.

Comment: I am using Channel Menu Code Settings - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.embedded_menu_code_changes.htm&type=5. From this code, I would like to access LWC DOM.

Answer (score 0):

As a short term solution you can try to disable Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components (GA) checkbox in Settings --> Session Settings.

By the way, it's better to revise the component's logic and avoid accessing Shadow DOM because Salesforce can enforce usage of Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components in the future.